# How to hide button in JQM datebox input field?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, datebox

I am using jqm date box as follows

```
    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:35%;">
        <input name="mydate" id="myDate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-theme="c" data-options='{"mode": "datebox","noButtonFocusMode": true,"noButton":true,"overrideDateFormat":"%d-%m-%Y","centerHoriz": true,"closeCallback": "dateChange();"}'/>
    </div>
```

In my text box there is a button and I need to hide the button , what I can do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try useButton: false:

```
<input name="Date1" id="Date1" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "useButton": false}' />
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/3s7R8/)**